# gedit doesn't open in terminal nor by searching in applications

Tags: command-line, apt, gedit

Since a time ago I'm not able to open files on gedit and it keeps crashing when I try to open it by clicking the program in the launcher or trying to open it in the terminal.
When I try to open it in terminal it shows this message:

```
~$ gedit
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I don't know what's happening and I can't figure out how to fix it. I've already tried to install, reinstall and uninstall gedit, running apt-get update, clean, autoremove etc but nothing works.

Edit: OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and gedit version is 3.18.3

When using `env | grep -Ei 'display|XDG_'` the following is shown:

```
~$ env | grep -Ei 'display|XDG_'
XDG_VTNR=7
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/guilherme
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
```

Comment: Does `ldd $(type -p gedit)` show anything missing?

Comment: What Version of gedit? what O.S. version? Add those to your question by editing it, not by posting a comment.

Comment: @waltinator it shows a lot of things, should I paste here?

Comment: Please paste in the original question and render output from a terminal window as `code` by indenting each line (with 4 spaces).

Comment: It does NOT show any missing libraries, thus need not to have been posted. However, thanks for the formatting. Could we see `env | grep -Ei 'display|XDG_'` ?